# Find "base" frequency of pulse wave

Tags: fft, frequency

I have some samples that are read from a square [pulse wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_wave) and I'm looking for a way to find the characteristics of this wave.

It's a pulse wave, let $T_1$ be the non-pulse duration and $T_2$ to be the pulse duration, usually $T_1$ is bigger than $T_2$.

I would like to know the base frequency, e.g., the frequency that includes $T_1+T_2$.
Can I do this using an FFT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Sample a few cycles, window, and do a FFT. The highest peak will be found at the base frequency (T1+T2) of your wave. With "spectral reassignment" you might get more precise results.

Comment: Will it work with square wave ?

Comment: Certainly. A square wave will have ,,overtones'' at multiples of the base frequency, but the base frequency will have maximum amplitude.